# How to watch value of object which is object

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have an object like this: 
`var obj = {key1: "hello",
key2: {keyA: "1", keyB: "2"}}`

I am currently using this code to watch when a values of a selected key changes:

```
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
        enumerable : false,
        configurable : true,
        writable : false,
        value : function(prop, handler) {
            var oldval = this[prop], newval = oldval, getter = function() {
                return newval;
            }, setter = function(val) {
                oldval = newval;
                return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
            };

            if (
            delete this[prop]) {// can't watch constants
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                    get : getter,
                    set : setter,
                    enumerable : true,
                    configurable : true
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

// object.unwatch
if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
        enumerable : false,
        configurable : true,
        writable : false,
        value : function(prop) {
            var val = this[prop];
            delete this[prop];
            // remove accessors
            this[prop] = val;
        }
    });
}

obj.watch("key1", function(id, oldval, newval) {

    console.log(newval)

});
`
```

and when "hello" changes i can handle events. But how could i handle an event when the property of an object changes (Key2) without watchin' with the previous function all the elements of the object(KeyA and KeyB)?

better said.. When an object changes is possible to get notified without monitoring all elements of that object?

Thaaanku

Answer (score 1):

> When an object *[property]* changes is possible to get notified without monitoring all elements of that object?

No. Your `watch` function relies on getters/setters, which are always property-specific. What you can do:

- Implement your object as a [`Proxy`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies), which is designed to do exactly what you want. Yet, it is only a draft and currently only [supported in Firefox' Javascript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).
- Use [`Object.observe`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aobserve), which however is only a draft as well.
- Use an explicit getter/setter method that gets the updated property name as an argument

Answer (score 0):

As you can see with the polyfill that enables watch to work on non-compliant Browers, watching for property change can be easily implemented in javascript.
Since what you need is different from any existing feature, you have to go for a custom feature, that will look for any change down the property chain, with a property change handler like : `function handleObjectChange(obj, oldPropValue, newPropValue, propertyPath)` where propertyPath is an array leading to the property that changed (expl1 : ['KeyA'] ; expl2 : ['TimeData', 'duration'] ), and `oldPropValue`/ `newPropValue` are the old/new value for that property that just changed.
`propertyPath` is null/undefined when the object itself changed, and in this case `old/new PropertyValue` contains the old/new value of the object.

Obviously that's just one way to achieve what you seek, but the basic point is : since it is a specific need, build your own specific answer.